# GDB does not see any threads besides

Tags: multithreading, gdb

GDB does not see any threads besides the one in which crash occurred; or SIGTRAP kills my program when I set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This frequently happen on Linux, especially on embedded targets. There are two common causes:

- you are using glibc, and you have stripped `libpthread.so.0`
- mismatch between `libpthread.so.0` and `libthread_db.so.1`

GDB itself does not know how to decode "thread control blocks" maintained by glibc and considered to be glibc private implementation detail. It uses `libthread_db.so.1` (part of glibc) to help it do so. Therefore, `libthread_db.so.1` and `libpthread.so.0` must match in version and compilation flags. In addition, `libthread_db.so.1` requires certain non-global symbols to be present in `libpthread.so.0`.

Solution: use `strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0` instead of `strip libpthread.so.0`.

If you are doing remote debugging, make sure `libpthread.so.0` on target and `libthread_db.so.1` on host match.